# How to set up a custom domain prefix for my website's url

Tags: url, web, dns, prefix

I just need to know what the name for the mail in:

**mail.**google.com

would be named

I thought 'custom domain prefix' made sense, but that doesn't seem to be it.
**Please provide a link to documentation if possible, or just a proper search query.**

Also, would it be a good idea to use these prefixes? Basically I have a site called smokelessmi.org and I want to make a prefix a2.smokelessmi.org for the city (Ann Arbor, Michigan) since this is a localized website.

Eventually I want to add other cities in Michigan, but I'm just starting with this one.

Comment: I think the correct terminology is "subdomain."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprisingly there's a plethora of rfc's ([rfc1591](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1591) [rfc2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) and [rfc2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181) to name just a few) that talk about the structure of domain names, and [this quote from rfc2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-11) stresses the hierarchical nature of DNS

> Occasionally it is assumed that the Domain Name System serves only the
> purpose of mapping Internet host names to data, and mapping Internet
> addresses to host names.  This is not correct, the DNS is a general
> (if somewhat limited) hierarchical database, and can store almost any
> kind of data, for almost any purpose.

So, to the left of your Top Level Domain (.com in your example) and what's quite often called [second level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) (also used in the aforementioned rfc2606 and also in [rfc920](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc920)) or in short domain, you can still have a whole hierarchy of names.  Personally I like to think of the leftmost one as the host name, because if you're addressing a service chances are that the most specific one represents a computer.  The "intermediate ones" are commonly called subdomains.